# Create Arraylist as parameter of a function that accepts any type in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to kotlin with Android Studio. I have written a function in kotlin which accepts an Arraylist as input and randomly shuffles it -

```
fun randomize(array: ArrayList<Any>) { ... }
```

I want this function to accept ArrayList of any type but calling with following arguments gives type mismatch error -

```
val arr = ArrayList<Int>()
// ...
randomize(array = arr) // Gives Error
```

How can I use ArrayList that accepts any type. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make your function generic, like so:

```
fun <T> randomize(array: ArrayList<T>) {
    // do whatever you want to your `ArrayList`
}
```

But if you don't have any specific way in mind for how to do the shuffling, you can just use the [`shuffle`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/shuffle.html) method of the standard library:

```
val arr = ArrayList<Int>()
// ...
arr.shuffle()
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer and also suggesting shuffle.